# Putty dims in fullscreen mode

Tags: windows-7, putty

When I maximize my putty window, it looks fine, however, if I hit alt-enter to go fullscreen mode, the font dims. I've looked through putty and my display settings, and I can't find anything that seems to address it. How can I get the full-screen mode to look the same as the maximized window?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My LCD monitor was doing automatic brightness and contrast. I found this by playing with the monitor settings. When I hit the button for "Brightness/Contrast", it prompted me to turn off the auto mode so that it could be adjusted manually. I said yes to turn it off, but didn't actually adjust brightness/contrast. PuTTY now looks the same in fullscreen or otherwise.

Comment: Just popping in to say thank you for answering this question. I had low expectations when I searched for "putty dims in fullscreen mode". I would never have guessed it on my own, you saved me a great deal of frustration!

Comment: Thank you, I accidentally changed my settings on my monitor to dynamic contrast and for some reason it would only happen when I did a fullscreen on a command prompt.  I was going nuts trying to figure this out.